# Fast way to start a new line

Tags: math-mode, formatting, equations, line-breaking

I have quite a few equations in a latex document that are similar to this one here:

```
\mathbb{E}(\cos^2) =  
 \frac{\pi  \left(\beta  \left(8 \left(2 \alpha ^2+2 \alpha +1\right)
   \beta ^2-12 (2 \alpha +1) \beta +15\right) I_1(2 \beta )+2 \left(-3
   \left(4 \alpha ^2+4 \alpha +3\right) \beta ^2+(8 \alpha +4) \beta
   ^3+12 (2 \alpha +1) \beta -15\right) I_2(2 \beta )\right)}{64 \beta
   ^4}
```

Now, I am just looking for a fast way to split this equation into several terms without having to change much here. The problem is that this equation contains a fraction on the right side, so when I try to do it with align, I need to reorder the nominators and denominators, so that it works out.

Since I have to change like 40 of these guys, I would love to see a fast way to split these equations into several terms standing in different lines without having to change much here.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please always post complete documents.

If you are generating lots of these I'd set it up so line breaking is automatic.

Don't over-use `\left\right` and avoid big fractions:

[image]

If you are breaking by hand you could do better but if you need automatic solution of output from a CA system or similar...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\let\oldfrac\frac
\def\frac#1#2{\oldfrac{1}{#2}(#1)}

$\mathbb{E}(\cos^2) =  
 \frac{\pi  (\beta  (8 (2 \alpha ^2+2 \alpha +1)
   \beta ^2-12 (2 \alpha +1) \beta +15) I_1(2 \beta )+2 (-3
   (4 \alpha ^2+4 \alpha +3) \beta ^2+(8 \alpha +4) \beta
   ^3+12 (2 \alpha +1) \beta -15) I_2(2 \beta ))}{64 \beta
   ^4}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: two questions about this. I just put \let\oldfrac\frac
\def\frac#1#2{\oldfrac{1}{#2}(#1)} in front of my document and now all equations are affected, can I do it that way that this has only an effect on a local set of equations.  Second question: Apparently I don't get automatic line-breaking and only the denominator is in front of my equation, but I have to say that I am using the \begin{equation}...\end{equation} environment for equations.

Comment: You won't get automatic linebreaking in `equation`  use `center` you can use `\refstepcounter{equation}` `(\theequation)` to get automatic referencable equation numbers. The frac redefintion can be in the environment as I did it or inside any `{}` group or environment , or just explicitly restore `\frac` with `\let\frac\oldfrac`

Answer (score 2):

If you really *must* use a long fractional expression, I would use the `\splitfrac` macro of the `mathtools` package to split the long numerator. In order to enhance the readability of your equations, you shouldn't rely on TeX to find "good" line breaks. Instead, parse the equation yourself and find the best place for `\splitfrac` to introduce the line break.

I would also use curly braces and square brackets in addition to round parentheses to help the reader with the visual parsing of the hierarchy of parentheses. 
By the way, using `\left` and `\right` gives you *nothing* in the case of this equation: all round parentheses have *exactly the same size* since the material they enclose isn't "large".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbb{E}(\cos^2) =  
 \frac{\splitfrac{\pi  \bigl\{\beta  \bigl[8 (2 \alpha ^2+2 \alpha +1)
   \beta ^2-12 (2 \alpha +1) \beta +15\bigr] I_1(2 \beta )}
   {+2 \bigl[-3
   (4 \alpha ^2+4 \alpha +3) \beta ^2+(8 \alpha +4) \beta
   ^3+12 (2 \alpha +1) \beta -15\bigr] I_2(2 \beta ) \bigr\}}}{64 \beta^4}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the `\pi \{ ... \}` instead of `\pi ( ... )`?

Comment: @WChargin - for optical variety: curly braces for the outermost group, square brackets for the middle group, etc